# Recaptcha image challenge always occurs in Microsoft Edge after form submission (Invisible recaptcha)

Tags: microsoft-edge, invisible-recaptcha

I've just implemented invisible recaptcha into a web form. Everything works fine with Chrome. But with Microsoft Edge, the image challenge always occurs with every form submission. Which is embarrassing for the users of the website. An idea?

Thanks a lot for your insights and advice :o)

Laurent

Javascript code:

```
   window.onScriptLoad = function () {

        var htmlEl = document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha');

        var captchaOptions = {

          'sitekey': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          'size': 'invisible',
          'badge': 'inline',
          callback: window.onUserVerified

         };

        var inheritFromDataAttr = true;

        recaptchaId = window.grecaptcha.render(htmlEl, captchaOptions, inheritFromDataAttr);

    };

    window.onUserVerified = function (token) {

      $.ajax({

            url: 'process.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data : {

                'lastname'   : $("#lastnameField").val(),
                'firstname'  : $("#firstnameField").val(),
                'city'       : $("#cityField").val(),
                'postalCode' : $("#postalcodeField").val(),
                'g-recaptcha-response' : token

            },

            success:function(data) {

                // informs user that form has been submitted
                // and processed

                },

            error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){

                // informs user that there was a problem
                // processing form on server side

           }

       });

    };


    function onSubmitBtnClick () {

      window.grecaptcha.execute;

    }
```

HTML code:

```
<html>

  <head>

    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit&onload=onScriptLoad" async defer></script>    

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/petition.js"></script>

    ...

  </head>

  <body>

     <form id="petitionForm" onsubmit="return false;">

         <input id="lastnameField" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" required value="Doe">
         <input id="firstnameField" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" required value="John">
         <input id="postalcodeField" type="text" name="postalCode" placeholder="Postal Code" required value="ABCDEF">
         <input id="cityField" type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" value="Oslo">
         ....

         <input type="submit" name="login" class="g-2" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" id="signButton" data-callback='' value="Signer" onclick="onSubmitBtnClick();">

         <div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptchaElement" style="align-content: center"></div>

       </form>

       ...

  </body>
</html>
```